# Is there a correlation coefficent for "smooth" functions?

Tags: correlation, nonlinear-regression

There is Pearson's, which measures linear relationships. There is also Spearman's, which can detect monotonic relationships. I am wondering if there is a similar coefficient someone has come up with for measuring the "smoothness" of some data. By "smoothness," I don't mean differentiable, but more as the term is used in image processing, where close inputs yield close outputs.

My idea for such a metric: Given a reference point $(x_a,y_a)$ and a second data point $(x_b,y_b)$, let $w_{ab} = distance(x_a,x_b)$. Then the "smoothness" of the data is the weighted average of $distance(y_a,y_b)$ over all $a, b$ pairs with weights $w_{ab}$.

I'm wondering if a coefficient that measures something similar is already in widespread use. Seems to me it would be commonly used when a dataset is high-dimensional and one cannot simply graph the data to determine if nonlinear regression would be useful. Nothing is turning up in internet searches, but I suspect I am just not familiar with the academic terminology.

Comment: There are a great many.  Quite a few of them are modeled on or inspired by the [variogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram).

Comment: Somewhat related method using a very different approach than correlation. Reshef, D. N., Reshef, Y. A., Finucane, H. K., Grossman, S. R., McVean, G., Turnbaugh, P. J., … Sabeti, P. C. (2011). Detecting Novel Associations in Large Data Sets. *Science*, 334(6062), 1518–1524. https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1205438